# Extract characters out of string in php

Tags: php, string

Lets say the string is  Motive S01E13 HDTV x264 EVOLVE eztv 
I need to find out which episode is in this string. It is Obviously season 1 episode 13. 
I need to extract the 13 out of the string. I'm newer to PHP . So, lets say:

```
$title = 'Motive S01E13 HDTV x264 EVOLVE eztv';
```

I need to find 'E' and see if the next two characters are Numerical values. I assume...
Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$title = 'Motive S01E13 HDTV x264 EVOLVE eztv';
preg_match('/s\d\de(\d\d)/i', $title, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // 13
```

This will output `13`, like you're looking for. It will work on any similarly formatted string, and will always output the episode number (as long as the format S00E00 is always followed). It is also case insensitive, if you care about that.

Comment: I think it's been cleared in the comment and the OP checked the given demo too and accepted the answer as well, so what is your problem ?

Comment: Also your, answer is not right because it won't work if there is only one digit like, `$title = 'Motive S01E7 HDTV x264 EVOLVE eztv';`, [check this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NUm59i).

Comment: all episodes are two digits

Comment: @SheikhHeera The OP very specifically states "I need to find 'E' and see if the next two characters are Numerical values". My answer does that; yours doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
$title = 'Empire S01E13 HDTV x264 EVOLVE eztv';
preg_match('/e(\d{2})/i', $title, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // 13
```

[**DEMO.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jAjkRl)

Comment: so it finds the first occurence?

Comment: Yes, it does, isn't that you asked for ?

Comment: @DDukesterman This is highly flawed. This will find the first capital letter E in the string, whether it's followed by a digit or not. It also doesn't extract the 13, as the question asked (it extracts `E13`).

Comment: @Duotrigesimal, I think it's been cleared in the comment and the `OP` checked the given demo too and accepted the answer as well, so what is your problem ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera, as I mentioned in my comment, I think this answer is wrong. The OP accepted your answer because it happened to work ok with his example. But, when he applies the answer to other similarly formatted strings, he will get unexpected results (example: `Empire S01E13 HDTV etc` will just output `E`.